# Why did my static analyzer fail to find potential uninitialized read?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I am wondering why static analyzer tools I use were unable to detect the following simple error (potentially unitialized variable):

```
    S08 GPS_Nmea::handler(GPS_INF *pGps, U08 *pRcvd) {
      S08 sErr;
      U08 byte;
      U08 mask = 0;
      U08 stat_mask;

      while (Q08_GetLength(&gps_q)) {
        sErr = Q08_Read(&gps_q, &byte, 1);
        if (sErr != Q_OK)
          continue;
        if ((EPBEXSTN.RS_Settings.D == RS485_NMEA_OUT) ||
            (EPBEXSTN.RS_Settings2.D == RS485_NMEA_OUT) ||
            (EPBEXSTN.RS_Settings3.D == RS485_NMEA_OUT)) {
          if (ts.p_dev != 0)
            ts.p_dev->write(&byte, 1);
        }
        sErr = _gps_fsm(byte);
        if (sErr == TRUE) {
          sErr = _gps_parse(gps_buf, pGps, &stat_mask);
          gps_rx_state = GPS_ST_WAIT;

          if (stat_mask == STR_RMC)
            mask |= STR_RMC;
          if (stat_mask == STR_GGA)
            mask |= STR_GGA;
          mask |= STR_ANY;
        }
      }

      if (pRcvd != NULL)
        *pRcvd = mask;

      return RC_ERR_NONE;
    }

S08 GPS_Nmea::_gps_parse (char* pBuf, GPS_INF* pGps, U08* pRcvd)
{
    S08 sErr;

    if ((memcmp(pBuf, "$GPRMC", 6) == 0) ||
        (memcmp(pBuf, "$GLRMC", 6) == 0) ||
        (memcmp(pBuf, "$GNRMC", 6) == 0))
    {
        APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $xxRMC parse\r\n"));
        //APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: string - %s\r\n", gps_buf));

        GpsTmp = *pGps;
        sErr = _gprmc_parse (pBuf, &GpsTmp);
        if (sErr == RC_ERR_NONE)
        {
            *pGps = GpsTmp;
            *pRcvd = STR_RMC;

            if (pGps->valid == FALSE)
                APP_PRINTF (GPS_WARNING, ("-W- gps_lib: gps data isn't valid\r\n"));
        }
        else
        {
            APP_PRINTF (GPS_ERROR, ("-E- gps_lib: _gprmc_parse() error\r\n"));
            clr_struct (pGps);
        }

        return sErr;
    }
    else if ((memcmp(pBuf, "$GPGGA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GLGGA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GNGGA", 6) == 0))
    {
        APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $xxGGA parse\r\n"));
        //APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: string - %s\r\n", gps_buf));

        GpsTmp = *pGps;
        sErr = _gpgga_parse (pBuf, &GpsTmp);
        if (sErr == RC_ERR_NONE)
        {
            *pGps = GpsTmp;
            *pRcvd = STR_GGA;
        }
        else
        {
            APP_PRINTF (GPS_ERROR, ("-E- gps_lib: _gpgga_parse() error\r\n"));
            clr_struct (pGps);
        }

        return sErr;
    }
    else if ((memcmp(pBuf, "$GPGSV", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GLGSV", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GNGSV", 6) == 0) )
  {
    APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $xxGSV parse\r\n"));

        sErr = _gpgsv_parse (pBuf);
        if (sErr == RC_ERR_NONE)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            APP_PRINTF (GPS_ERROR, ("-E- gps_lib: _gpgga_parse() error\r\n"));
        }
        return sErr;
  }
    else if ((memcmp(pBuf, "$GPGSA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GLGSA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GNGSA", 6) == 0) )
  {
    APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $xxGSA parse\r\n"));
        GpsTmp = *pGps;
        sErr = _gpgsa_parse (pBuf, &GpsTmp);
        if (sErr == RC_ERR_NONE)
        {
            *pGps = GpsTmp;
            *pRcvd = STR_GSA;
        }
    else
        {
            APP_PRINTF (GPS_ERROR, ("-E- gps_lib: _gpgga_parse() error\r\n"));
        }
        return sErr;
  }
    else if ((memcmp(pBuf, "$GPZDA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GLZDA", 6) == 0) ||
             (memcmp(pBuf, "$GNZDA", 6) == 0) )
  {
    APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $xxZDA parse\r\n"));
        GpsTmp = *pGps;
        sErr = _gpzda_parse (pBuf);
        if (sErr == RC_ERR_NONE)
        {
            *pGps = GpsTmp;
            *pRcvd = STR_ZDA;
        }
    else
        {
            APP_PRINTF (GPS_ERROR, ("-E- gps_lib: _gpzda_parse() error\r\n"));
        }
        return sErr;
  }
    else if (memcmp(pBuf, "$PMTK705", 8) == 0) 
  {
    APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $PMTK705 parse\r\n"));
    int ver_len = strlen(pBuf+9) - 4;
    if (ver_len > sizeof(tsk_gps.gps_version)-1)
      ver_len = sizeof(tsk_gps.gps_version)-1;
    memcpy(tsk_gps.gps_version,pBuf+9,ver_len);
        return RC_ERR_NONE;
  }
    else if (memcmp(pBuf, "$PMTKSPF", 8) == 0) 
  {
    static U08 jamming_active_cnt = 0;
    static U08 jamming_prev_state = FALSE;
    APP_PRINTF (GPS_TRACE, ("-I- gps: $PMTKSPF parse\r\n"));
    tsk_gps.jamming_pmtk_to = 0;
    if (memcmp(pBuf, "$PMTKSPF,3", 10) == 0)
    { if (jamming_active_cnt < 60) jamming_active_cnt ++; }
    else
    { if (jamming_active_cnt != 0) jamming_active_cnt --; }
    if (jamming_active_cnt > 30)
    {
      if (bsp.m_DevInfo.jamming_gps)
      {
        tsk_gps.jamming_data = TRUE;
        if (jamming_prev_state == FALSE)
        {
          ev_bus.add(GLOB_EV_JAMMING_GPS);
        }
      }
      jamming_prev_state = TRUE;
    }
    else
      jamming_prev_state = FALSE;
        return RC_ERR_NONE;
  }
#if defined (MAKE_ERA)
    else if (memcmp(pBuf, "$PSTMGETALGOOK", 14) == 0)
  {
        if (memcmp(pBuf+15, "1,1", 3) == 0)
    {
            pGps->fde_status = 1;
        }
    else
        {
            pGps->fde_status = 0;
        }
        return sErr;
  }
#endif
    else
    {
        gps_buf[6] = 0;
        //APP_PRINTF (GPS_WARNING, ("-W- gps: undef string - %s\r\n", gps_buf));
    }

    return RC_ERR_DATA;
}
```

Bug explanation:
Variable `stat_mask` unitialized in `handler()` function (line 44) able to be unchanged in called `_gps_parse()` function too (line 59).
Seems to be an obvious error (for static analyzing tools) but none of the tools I used pointed me to that.

Edit 1.
Full source code added:
[gpc_nmea.cpp](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3naK/nftoLCjBs)
Here you can see function

Used analyzer tool is [PVS Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/)

**Edit 2.**
Here is simplified version of code containing that bug:

```
include <stdio.h>

void func(int a, int *px) {
    if (a == 1) 
    {
        *px = 1;
    }
}

int main (void)
{    
    int x;
    func(2, &x);
    printf(x);
}
```

Can someone suggest me any analyzing tool that able point me that variable `x` might be uninitialized? Can't believe that humanity still doesn't have such solution.

Comment: This is not C code. I'll re-tag it for you.

Comment: "static analyzer tools I use" - what are those tools? How are they configured? Can you reduce your code to a minimal example that reproduces the error, but still lacks the warning? A modern C++ compiler should definitely emit a warning for that. [Simple example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d8a3f5902cf5d3f)

Comment: So the issue is that when analyzing this function it assumes that gps_parse() writes stat_mask, but it didn't check whether gps_parse() actually does in all cases and then feed that back to the analysis of this function? That sounds like a missing feature in your analyzer.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz but the OP's example not as simple as your simple example.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oh, that loop encloses the write? I blame terrible formatting.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The write is conditional, e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b80ba83fda6c2e7b

Comment: Sure, but all of my other questions still stand. "My unspecified tool failed to work in this case, why?" is unanswerable without knowing what that tool was in the first place. And even then, I expect something along the lines of either "it's impossible" or "it's just not implemented".

Comment: source code added. Used analyzing tool is PVS Studio.

Comment: Rup, yeah! Exactly that situation. Can't believe that nowadays compilers/analyzers unable to detect such bug.

Comment: You should probably raise this with PVS Studio as a defect or a feature suggestion if you haven't already.

Comment: Can someone suggest me static analyzer that able to detect such type of bug?

Comment: `printf(x);` causes undefined behaviour, the pre-scan compilation should detect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at the moment the PVS-Studio analyzer is not able to detect this error. The case seems to be very simple, but actually such kind of the analysis is quite complicated. We are constantly improving the interprocedural analysis and Data Flow Analysis. We hope that in time it will become possible to detect such errors as well.

P.S. In such cases static analyzers usually give in, as they cannot take into account all the interconnections and track the variables changing. Dynamic code analyzers perform the search of uninitialized variables well. Try one of the dynamic analyzers.

P.P.S.But just don't try to choose what to use: static or dynamic analysis. Some errors can be found greatly by static analyzers, others - by dynamic ones. These methodologies supplement each other perfectly. More details: [Static and Dynamic Code Analysis](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0248/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually writing to `*pRcvd` within a condition, a static analyzer might not be able to easily determine for sure whether this condition will ever evaluate to false. Especially if the value in the condition comes from a linked library.

I could imagine that a static analyzer may decide to not warn at all - if it is not sure. Since false positive warnings are annoying and people tend to ignore warnings if there are too many of them.

Although it may be theoretically possible to catch such an error, assuming it is possible to determine during compile time, it might be just quite hard to do so and hence may not be implemented in your static analyzer.